# DataGrid with Picture

Tags: vb6

I have a DataGrid in Visual Basic 6. This DataGrid displays a list of product just like what see below:
[image]

I want to change image in the Image control whenever the user selects a product from the DataGrid. I am doing this thru the code below:

```
Private Sub txtBarcode_Change()
On Error GoTo nosuchfile
    picture.picture = App.Path & "Images\products\" & txtBarcode.Text & ".jpg"
nosuchfile:
picture.picture = App.Path & "Images\products\no_image.jpg"
End Sub
```

txtBarcode is a hidden textbox that contains the barcode/id that is currently selected in the DataGrid.

MY PROBLEM: The image doesn't seems to change.

Answer (score 0):

to load a picture you need to call LoadPicture()

```
Picture1.Picture = LoadPicture("c:\temp\pic.bmp")
```